# Are there no Wildfly 8 / Java EE 7 quickstart archetypes?

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly, maven-archetype

I remember from Jboss AS 7 and earlier there being convenient maven archetypes available that would set up maven projects with the apropriate dependencies and BOM, but I can't find any for Wildfly/Java EE 7.

I found the BOMs and instruction on how to manually add them to a project, but I'm wondering if I'm not missing preconfigured archetypes that exist somewhere.

Also, if there are indeed no updated archetypes: why not ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WildFly Java EE 7 archetypes are available at:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly.archetype

Is that what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 6):

Actually there are not yet official wildfly archetypes but you can start with **webapp-javaee7** such as:

```
mvn -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes   \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-javaee7              \
    -DarchetypeVersion=0.1-SNAPSHOT                   \
    -DarchetypeRepository=https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ \
    -DgroupId=com.sample                              \
    -DartifactId=javaee7-sample                       \
    -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT                            \
    -Dpackage=com.sample                              \
    -Darchetype.interactive=false                     \
    --batch-mode --update-snapshots archetype:generate
```

Then you can further refine your pom.xml by adding Bill of Materials and the WildFly plugin. See this [Maven configuration tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/wildfly-8/maven-configuration-for-java-ee-7-projects-on-wildfly) for info about the available BOMs.

Answer (score 3):

[Java EE 7 Maven Archetype](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/java_ee_7_maven_archetypes) - `org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:webapp-javaee7` is now also available in standard (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) maven repository.

```bash
mvn -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes   \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-javaee7              \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.1                            \
    -DgroupId=com.sample                              \
    -DartifactId=javaee7-sample                       \
    -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT                            \
    -Dpackage=com.sample                              \
    -Darchetype.interactive=false                     \
    --batch-mode --update-snapshots archetype:generate
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a maven archetype for Java EE 7 microservices-based application - [maven-archetype-javaee7-micro](https://github.com/agritsik/maven-archetype-javaee7-micro). It uses Arquillian for integration testing with 2 profiles for grassfish 4.1 and wildfly 8.2 containers.

Moreover, there is a sample application (JPA, JAX-RS) created via that archetype - [blog microservice](https://github.com/agritsik/javaee7-microservice)